# Why is the width of my safari viewport on my iPad only 768px instead of 1028px?

Tags: ipad, mobile-safari, device-width

Everywhere I read, the width of the screen on the Ipad 1 is 1024 x 768.

I have built a site using bootstrap and the collapsable nav button appears when viewing the site in landscape mode on my iPad. It should not. It should only appear for viewports that are less than 1024px in width.

I then sniffed out the width as jQuery sees it using $(window).width(); and it is reporting only 768px x 467px;

I have the following metatag:

meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"

Comment: The status bar height is 20px and the navigation bar height is 44px. That's likely the difference off the original 768px.

Comment: Thanks. It's the width I'm concerned with - not the height.

Comment: Right, so this issue is limited to only portrait orientation then?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In landscape mode the iPad zooms content in so that the effective viewport with is the same as in portrait mode.

Try this - ISTR it's supposed to force all windows to 1:1 zoom, and prevents user zooming.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=1.0,initial-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: That's the ticket!!!! It also works with: meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale = 1" Thanks so much!